# QGIS vector field marker not respecting map rotation

Tags: qgis, symbology, rotate, vector-field

I’m working on a map the shows point displacement between two dates. These are survey benchmarks that are surveyed periodically to observe slope movement. Symbolizing this in QGIS is straight forward with the vector field marker by supplying two fields with the displacement values (delta) in X and Y direction. The map and all the layers are in EPSG:3057 that uses meters. The displacement values are in meters as well. My problem is that I need to rotate the map 130° CCW for publication but the arrows do not follow the map rotation (like a north arrow for example). The arrows keep point in the same “paper direction” or “screen direction”. Am I missing something in the symbology setting for the vector field marker?

The layer is a shapefile and this is QGIS 3.14.15 running in Windows 10.

[image: QGIS 3.14.15 - rotation map with vector field merkers]

Comment: This has been reported as a bug/issue https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40916

Comment: This bug has been fixed with QGIS version 3.18 thanks to Nyall Dawson!